# Is it possible to play a Blu-ray Disc on iMac?

Tags: imac, blu-ray

There is no any drive with my iMac and I know apple doesn't have program that could play Blu-ray until now, so can anyone give me some ideas about how can I make my iMac play Blu-ray disc movies?

Answer (score 0):

You might to check out this [MacWorld url](http://www.macworld.com/article/2042431/watch-and-rip-blu-ray-movies-on-your-mac.html).

There are several Blu-ray external USB drives available, but the url above will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm also a frequent Mac user who found the right Blu-ray tool including software and BD drive http://www.macblurayplayer.com/macgo-bluray-player-drive.htm